# overwrite Laravel exception handler in Laravel package development

Tags: php, laravel, exception, package, handler

I'm writing a Laravel package and there are some routes that return JSON response
and I want to have my own exception handler in the package, not the Laravel handler
But I can't overwrite that. there was a [discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/custom-exception-handler-based-on-route-group) about it but it does not work anymore

I write this singleton in my package service provider and controller construct method but it does not work

my service provider:

```php
namespace Rabsana\Trade\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TradeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(
            Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
            Rabsana\Trade\Exceptions\Handler::class
        );
    }


    public function register()
    {
        // 
    }
```

my controller:

```php
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        \App::singleton(
            Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
            Rabsana\Trade\Exceptions\Handler::class
        );
    }
    public function index()
    {
        throw new ModelNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

my handler at the package:

```php
namespace Rabsana\Trade\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }


    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Throwable               $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {

        dd('here');
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

after throwing the exception the render method at `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` will be executed but I want the `Rabsana\Trade\Exceptions\Handler.php` be executed

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of another method to override the Laravel Exception handler (besides the method shown in your example) without requiring the user to make manual changes to their `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` file or manually overriding the binding for the Handler.

What you could do, is require the user to add a piece of code to their `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` file that will trigger your package.

[Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel/) does that in the following way:

```
// App/Exceptions/Handler.php

public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        if ($this->shouldReport($e) && app()->bound('sentry')) {
            app('sentry')->captureException($e);
        }
    });
}
```